# In visual studio '13 how do I make it so I can include dll files in a relative sub folder of my exe?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, subdirectory

In C# I know there's a way to edit the assemble config file or something of that sort, but for C++ I have no clue how to make it so instead of having all my dll's in the root directory put into something like /libs or /bin/ folder and my exe will look there for the dll files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're loading the DLL at runtime you can simply write `hDll = LoadLibrary("subFolder\\test.dll");`. At first Windows looks for the DLL in the directory your program is located. Therefore `test.dll` will be found in `app_dir/subFolder/test.dll` (app_dir = path of executable). Note that this also works if the current directory is different to `app_dir`.

Look at MSDN for more [information about DLL searching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your EXE doesn't look for DLL files. That means it doesn't matter whether you're using C++ or C#. Visual Studio is even less relevant as it's not even present when your EXE runs.

Windows looks for DLLs. In your C# example, Windows uses the assembly manifest to guide the search. In your C++ example, you didn't add one, so Windows uses just the default paths. The solution is thus obvious: use a similar manifest.